# How to handle long click in multi image view

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener

I have 8-numbers of `ImageView` in my layout and I had set the `LongClickListner` to all of the `ImageView`. If the user long click on the image (any image), the image will be saved in the gallery. But my problem here is when the user long click on 8th Image, the 1st or others (1 of them) will saved in the gallery. What I want is when the user long click on 8th image, the 8th image will saved not the others.

```
 @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.saveImage:
            if(img1.isLongClickable() ){
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)img1.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                Random random = new Random();
                int x = random.nextInt(1000000);
                saveImageUtils.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(),bitmap,String.valueOf(x));
                //SaveImage(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image Saved to Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }else if(img2.isLongClickable()){
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)img2.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                Random random = new Random();
                int x = random.nextInt(1000000);
                saveImageUtils.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(),bitmap,String.valueOf(x));
                //SaveImage(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image Saved to Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }else if(img3.isLongClickable()){
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)img3.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                Random random = new Random();
                int x = random.nextInt(1000000);
                saveImageUtils.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(),bitmap,String.valueOf(x));
                //SaveImage(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image Saved to Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }else if(img4.isLongClickable()){
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)img4.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                Random random = new Random();
                int x = random.nextInt(1000000);
                saveImageUtils.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(),bitmap,String.valueOf(x));
                //SaveImage(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image Saved to Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }else if(img5.isLongClickable()){
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)img5.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                Random random = new Random();
                int x = random.nextInt(1000000);
                saveImageUtils.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(),bitmap,String.valueOf(x));
                //SaveImage(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image Saved to Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }else if(img6.isLongClickable()){
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)img6.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                Random random = new Random();
                int x = random.nextInt(1000000);
                saveImageUtils.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(),bitmap,String.valueOf(x));
                //SaveImage(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image Saved to Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }else if(img7.isLongClickable()){
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)img7.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                Random random = new Random();
                int x = random.nextInt(1000000);
                saveImageUtils.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(),bitmap,String.valueOf(x));
                //SaveImage(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image Saved to Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }else if(img8.isLongClickable()){
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)img8.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                Random random = new Random();
                int x = random.nextInt(1000000);
                saveImageUtils.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(),bitmap,String.valueOf(x));
                //SaveImage(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image Saved to Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }

    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Show full code snippet. Can't understand the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

What you presented above is like this:

1. Apparently your ImageView's have `OnLongClickListener`s assigned
2. User is clicking toolbar's menu item `R.id.saveImage` and you're trying to save image based on `isLongClickable` indication

If true, the above is wrong because `isLongClickable` is basically just indication that given control has `OnLongClickListener` assigned.

What you should be doing: either do your saving inside every respective `OnLongClickListener`(and its `onLongClick` will give you the view, that is, ImageView) OR if you need to do the saving only upon `R.id.saveImage` click, then in `OnLongClickListener` you should somehow tell your app that given ImageView was long clicked, and then upon `R.id.saveImage` click, iterate through recorded list of ImageView long clicks and perform the saving.